# How to host node.js MS Bot Framework Chatbot using IIS

Tags: node.js, iis, botframework, chatbot, iis-8.5

I'm trying to host the default MS Bot Framework echo bot using Node.js via IIS. However, it does not seem to be working. Do I need to change anything in the code to make it work?

I've tried changing the port from 3987 to  80, but it doesn't start. I'm new to node so I don't exactly know what the problem is.

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// Licensed under the MIT License.

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const path = require('path');
const restify = require('restify');

// Import required bot services.
// See https://aka.ms/bot-services to learn more about the different parts of a bot.
const { BotFrameworkAdapter } = require('botbuilder');

// This bot's main dialog.
const { MyBot } = require('./bot');

// Import required bot configuration.
const ENV_FILE = path.join(__dirname, '.env');
dotenv.config({ path: ENV_FILE });

// Create HTTP server
const server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, () => {
    console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }`);
    console.log(`\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator`);
    console.log(`\nTo test your bot, see: https://aka.ms/debug-with-emulator`);
});

// Create adapter.
// See https://aka.ms/about-bot-adapter to learn more about how bots work.
const adapter = new BotFrameworkAdapter({
    appId: process.env.MicrosoftAppId,
    appPassword: process.env.MicrosoftAppPassword
});

// Catch-all for errors.
adapter.onTurnError = async (context, error) => {
    // This check writes out errors to console log .vs. app insights.
    console.error(`\n [onTurnError]: ${ error }`);
    // Send a message to the user
    await context.sendActivity(`Oops. Something went wrong!`);
};

// Create the main dialog.
const myBot = new MyBot();

// Listen for incoming requests.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (context) => {
        // Route to main dialog.
        await myBot.run(context);
    });
});
```

I already have HTTPS setup on my IIS and I should be able to test it once I get it to work.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The Bot Framework works with bots deployed on any cloud hosting service, as long as you have an internet-accessible endpoint and a valid HTTPS cert. Can you verify if you have the valid HTTPS certificate? Also, can you post what error are you getting?

Comment: Hi, I'm not getting an error actually. I just don't know which port I should listen to, should I retain the code and listen to port 3987 or do I need to change the code to listen to port 80? Thanks.

Comment: when you say it does not "start", you mean it does not connect or it gets connected but doesn't run? Can you try using the emulator to connect and test? You can refer to https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode, https://harveywilliams.net/blog/installing-iisnode and https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx tutorials to get started with.